# How can I make box-shadow appear above a div?

Tags: html, css

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QqME6/) is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

The `box-shadow` from the upper `div` won't appear on top of the `div` below it. From what I understand, I need to set the `z-index` so it will appear on top and that only works on elements with `position: relative;` but it's still not appearing.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
    background-color: blue;
}

#middle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: orange;
}

#innerMiddle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
</div>

<div id="middle">
    <div id="innerMiddle">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's `#top` and its `box-shadow` that you want to appear on top, so give that `position: relative` instead of giving `position: relative` to `#middle`. There's no need for `z-index: 0`.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/QqME6/1/

```css
#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
    background-color: blue;
    
    position: relative;
}

#middle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: orange;
}

#innerMiddle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
</div>

<div id="middle">
    <div id="innerMiddle">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Change your CSS to:

```css
#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
    background-color: blue;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

#middle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
</div>

<div id="middle">
    <div id="innerMiddle">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use position: relative in upper div not below div

```css
#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

#middle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 0;
  /* position: relative; */
  background-color: orange;
}

#innerMiddle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="middle">
      <div id="innerMiddle"></div>
    </div>
```